# Creating a language dropdown menu with reroute and local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I have a web application using Umbraco (MVC .NET) that has (for now) only two roots. They are named "English" and "Swedish". English is the default webpage and Swedish should be optional for the user. In order for the user to be able to change language I display them in a dropdown menu using Razor:

```
@{
   List<SelectListItem> languages= new List<SelectListItem>();
   foreach (var language in Model.Content.Siblings())
   {
      languages.Add(new SelectListItem
      {
         Text = language.Name,
         Value = language.Url
    });
}
@Html.DropDownList("LanguageSelect",new SelectList(languages,"Value","Text"), htmlAttributes: new { id = "LanguageSelect" });
}
```

This properly outputs the names of the roots at root level. Now using javascript i reroute using onchange:

```
document.getElementById("LanguageSelect").onchange = function() {
    window.location.href = this.value;      
};
```

This works for going from one language to another. Now the hard part starts: because this dropdown exists in my master template inherited by all views, when a new view is loaded, everything from the template is reloaded. Therefor the dropdown is reloaded and the selected language is lost in the dropdown. Instead of looking at the URL for which value should be set in the dropdown I wanted to use local storage. So I tried setting this in the onchange function for the dropdown:

```
localStorage.setItem("LanguageSelectStoredUrl", this.value);
```

But this saves the URL. I would like to save the text aswell, i.e. "Swedish" and just set the current value of the dropdown to the stored value. This should work, right? If so how do I do that? Any reasons not to?

Another reason why I wanted to do it this way is because I want the user in a later session not having to choose language again by using:

```
$(document).onload(function(){
   if(localStorage.getItem("LanguageSelectStoredValue") != null){
      // Check if the dropdown value is equal to the stored value
      // If so do nothing
      // Else reroute to locally stored URL
```

But as I don't know how to store the text value of the dropdown I cant do this and maybe there is a more fitting event to hook on to than onload?

Here is a summary of my questions that I need help with in order to fulfill the task at hand:

1. How do I get the text of the selected dropdown item?
2. How do I programmaticly select one of the values in the dropdown?
3. Is there a better event to hook on to than onload?

Anything else that I might have overlooked?

Thanks!

Comment: `$( "#LanguageSelect option:selected" ).text();` should give you the selected text of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get the selected text of a drop down list:

   JavaScript:

   ```
   var languageSelect = document.getElementById("LanguageSelect");
   var selectedText = languageSelect.options[languageSelect.selectedIndex].text;
   ```

   jQuery:

   ```
   $('#LanguageSelect option:selected').text();
   ```
2. Using `$("#LanguageSelect").val('ValFromDdl');` will allow you to select an item in a drop down list.
3. You can use `$(document).ready` to read your storage object and initialize the drop down list.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. I'm having problems with question nr 2. Maybe I was unclear. I'm wondering how to programmaticly select a value in the dropdown, not overwrite an existing value